# Cant detect if PWA is installed on first page view?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a desktop Chrome extension that I normally want to run on every domain. In `manifest.json`:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["contentScript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

However I don't want it to run for installed PWAs. In my content script I have this check:

```
const isInstalled =
  window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches ||
  window.matchMedia('(display-mode: fullscreen)').matches ||
  window.matchMedia('(display-mode: minimal-ui)').matches;
if (isInstalled) {
  // Don't run
} else {
  // Run
}
```

Technically it's still "running" but this type of check is OK for me. However there are 2 problems with this:

Firstly the check doesn't work the very first time the PWA is installed and opened, even if it does work after that.

Secondly, after the first view it does work for most PWAs that I tested (keep.google.com, [www.soundslice.com](http://www.soundslice.com), music.youtube.com) but for app.starbucks.com it doesn't work at all.

Comment: 1) The first time the tab is detached into a new window, it's the same page so your content scripts don't run again, but you can listen to `appinstalled` event (Chrome only) or try chrome.windows.onCreated or chrome.tabs.onDetached in the background script. 2) Try navigator.getInstalledRelatedApps

Comment: `getInstalledRelatedApps` doesn't work (at least for the YouTube PWA). I don't control the PWA's manifest and I'm not sure if the content script is running in the required context anyway. `appinstalled` does seem to work even though it's being depreciated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/appinstalled_event

Comment: For Starbucks I needed to listen for a change event on `window.matchMedia` and then it worked.